# Xcode: Show downloaded .txt content in label?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Probably really a rookie question here about xcode (for the iphone)..

When I issue this command;

NSString *externalData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://blah.com/userlist.txt"]];

I can see it's download from my webserver. 
How can I make this 1 line show in a label?

I tried;
label.text = externalData;
[externalData release];

But this doesn't seem to work..it seems to crash the app in the simulator.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It crashes because `+dataWithContentsOfURL:` returns an NSData* which is not an NSString*. You want `+stringWithContentsOfURL:` instead. Note though, that this will block the main thread, which may not be desirable.

Edit:

To be clear, code like this:

```
NSString* foo = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:...];
```

Where you replace the appropriate sections of code with your own values.

Comment: Deprecated. Use stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error: if you know the encoding or stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error: which tells you what encoding it used to interpret the data. The latter is probably sensible for text/* content-types with a charset= parameter.

Comment: Good point and good catch. I haven't used these classes of methods in a long time, so I don't keep up on their depreciation.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
I tried
 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.blah.com/xcode/userlist.txt"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
label.text = *content;

It tells me;

Incompatible type for argument 1 of setText .. 
I assume I have to do some conversion here?

I tried;

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",content];
But that just isn't is..
Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I eventually got it working with; 

content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURLURLWithString:@"http://www.iblah.com/xcode/userlist.txt"] encoding: 1 error: NULL];
label.text = content;

And in the .h file I had to put NSString *content;

And that did the job.
Thanks all